# How do I give particle effects to my dog in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I am in a normal survival world and I have a dog named Charles (name tag). I want to give him particle effects when he walks, attacks, and gets fed. I know you can give arrows and players effects but can't find anything about giving it to my dog. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, those are wolves, not dogs.

**Wolves walking detection**

There exists a scoreboard variable that detects if entities walked one cm.
`scoreboard objectives add walk custom:walk_one_cm`
Adding a walking variable called `walk`

I would suggest for you to create a datapack in this case, since this involves constant manipulation of variables which would be laggy and hard to accomplish by using in-game command blocks. The general plan:
Repeat Unconditional
`execute as @e[type=wolf,scores={walk=1..}] run say ParticleEffect`
Chained Conditional
`execute as @e[type=wolf] run scoreboard players reset @s walk`

**Attacking**
Similarly, create an attack objective
`scoreboard objectives add attack custom:damage_dealt`
Repeat Unconditional
`execute as @e[type=wolf,scores={attack=1..}] run say PetAttackingParticle`
chained Conditional
`execute as @e[type=wolf] run scoreboard players reset @s attack`

**Feeding**
I am not quite sure about this one since I cannot find a scoreboard obj associated with the action of feeding. Perhaps you should use objectives to detect the health change of the wolf, which would require 2 objectives one recording the health value of the wolf from the previous tick and see if the current objective matches the previous objective value. I assume that only by feeding can you increase the wolf's health in vanilla (save for health potions) so that should do the task for you. It would be pretty difficult to actually execute but I can provide you help if you are hell-bent on getting a feeding particle effect.

**How to use /particle**
WIth the addition of several new particles in 1.17 and 1.18 the syntax and arguments required for some specific particles such as dust and vibration is more complex, but generally you have to fill in `particle name`, `position at which to execute the particle effect (relative)`, `the coordinates displacements in x y z from the origin to the ending point of the particle`, `speed of particle`, `particle count`. I believe the Minecraft Wiki would be better if you are looking for detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

By default dogs have particle effects. It is possible that you have disabled the effects. You can re-enable them by pressing ESC -> Settings -> Video Settings -> change 'Particles' to 'All' or 'Reduced'.

Comment: sorry but that's not whta i am asking and as i note i am on education edtion/ bedrock

Comment: I believe they are asking how to give particles on the given events using /particle, not how to enable particles.